# Automated .kube/config file created with Terraform GKE module doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

We are using the below terraform module to create the GKE cluster and the local config file. But the kubectl command doesn't work. The terminal just keeps on waiting. Then we have to manually run the command `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` to fetch and set up the local config credentials post the cluster creation, and then the kubectl command works. It doesn't feel elegant to execute the `gcloud` command after the terraform setup. Therefore please help to correct what's wrong.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
        source = "hashicorp/google"
        version = ">= 3.42.0"
    }
    google-beta = {
        source = "hashicorp/google-beta"
        version = ">= 3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = var.gcp_creds
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

provider "google-beta" {
  credentials = var.gcp_creds
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

module "gke" {
  source                 = "terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google//modules/beta-private-cluster"
  project_id             = var.project_id
  name                   = "cluster"
  regional               = true
  region                 = var.region
  zones                  = ["${var.region}-a", "${var.region}-b", "${var.region}-c"]
  network                = module.vpc.network_name
  subnetwork             = module.vpc.subnets_names[0]
  ip_range_pods          = "gke-pod-ip-range"
  ip_range_services      = "gke-service-ip-range"
  horizontal_pod_autoscaling = true
  enable_private_nodes       = true
  master_ipv4_cidr_block     = "${var.control_plane_cidr}"
  node_pools = [
    {
      name                      = "node-pool"
      machine_type              = "${var.machine_type}"
      node_locations            = "${var.region}-a,${var.region}-b,${var.region}-c"
      min_count                 = "${var.node_pools_min_count}"
      max_count                 = "${var.node_pools_max_count}"
      disk_size_gb              = "${var.node_pools_disk_size_gb}"
      auto_repair               = true
      auto_upgrade              = true
    },
  ]
}


# Configure the authentication and authorisation of the cluster
module "gke_auth" {
  source = "terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google//modules/auth"
  depends_on   = [module.gke]
  project_id   = var.project_id
  location     = module.gke.location
  cluster_name = module.gke.name
}

# Define a local file that will store the necessary info such as certificate, user and endpoint to access the cluster
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  content  = module.gke_auth.kubeconfig_raw
  filename = "~/.kube/config"
}
```

**UPDATE**:
We found that the automated `.kube/config` file was created with the wrong public IP of the API Server whereas the one created with the gcloud command contains the correct IP of the API Server. Any guesses why terraform one is fetching the wrong public IP?

Comment: Where do you configure the `kubernetes` provider in your code?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE I have updated the code for your reference to include the provider info. We have not used the Kubernetes provider here but the cluster is setup properly

Comment: Please take a look at these two links:
1. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs
2. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/blob/main/_examples/gke/README.md